# Able to get image to move in Pygame; but I have to keep on pressing the button to make it move

Tags: python, pygame

So, I've used [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183265/how-to-move-sprite-in-pygame) to help me figure out an easy way into moving my player sprite in pygame. The only issue is that the buttons for movement have to be spammed in order for the sprite to move more than the five pixels specified every time the button is pressed.

Here's the code in full. The areas in question are the Player() class and the " player." areas in the loop:

```
import pygame

player_path = "downChara.png" #specifies image path

class Player(object): #representitive of the player's overworld sprite
        def __init__(self):
            self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha() #creates image, the player_path variable allowing it to be updated
            self.X = 284; # x co-ord of player
            self.Y = 184; # y co-ord of player


        def handle_keys(self): #handling the keys/inputs
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            dist = 5 #distance travelled in one frame of the program
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: #if down
                self.Y += dist #move down the length of dist
                player_path = "downChara.png" #change image to down
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
            elif key[pygame.K_UP]: #if up
                self.Y -= dist #move up the length of dist
                player_path = "upChara.png" #change to up
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: #etc.
                self.X += dist
                player_path = "rightChara.png"
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
            elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.X -= dist
                player_path = "leftChara.png"
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()


        def draw(self, surface): #draw to the surface/screen
            surface.blit(self.image, (self.X, self.Y))
             pygame.init() (width, height) = (600, 400) #specify window resolution bg_colour = (100,20,156) #specify bg colour

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) #create window pygame.display.set_caption('EduGame') #specify window name


player = Player() clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.display.flip() #paints screen gameRun = True #allow game events to loop/be carried out more than once

while gameRun: #while game is running:
       for event in pygame.event.get(): #all the events (movement, etc) to be here.
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the "x" is pressed
        pygame.quit() #quit game
        gameRun = False #break the loop.
        quit()

    player.handle_keys() #handle keys

    screen.fill(bg_colour) #draw background colour

    player.draw(screen) #draws player

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(40)
```

here are the specific areas that I mentioned:

```
class Player(object): #representitive of the player's overworld sprite
        def __init__(self):
            self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha() #creates image, the player_path variable allowing it to be updated
            self.X = 284; # x co-ord of player
            self.Y = 184; # y co-ord of player


        def handle_keys(self): #handling the keys/inputs
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            dist = 5 #distance travelled in one frame of the program
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: #if down
                self.Y += dist #move down the length of dist
                player_path = "downChara.png" #change image to down
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
            elif key[pygame.K_UP]: #if up
                self.Y -= dist #move up the length of dist
                player_path = "upChara.png" #change to up
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: #etc.
                self.X += dist
                player_path = "rightChara.png"
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
            elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.X -= dist
                player_path = "leftChara.png"
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()


        def draw(self, surface): #draw to the surface/screen
            surface.blit(self.image, (self.X, self.Y))
```

and:

```
player.handle_keys() #handle keys

screen.fill(bg_colour) #draw background colour

player.draw(screen) #draws player
```

the "player." isn't in any event.type if/elif loop, however when i try putting it under "event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN" it doesn't seem to have any effect.

This isn't necessarily a crippling error as I could try and adapt my game around it, however I think the game would run and look smoother if the player was able to just hold down the respective key(s) instead of spam-tapping them for a decade to try and navigate.

(as a bonus feel free to try and find a better way of updating the sprites path/location than what I did under the "def handle_keys(self)" function)

cheers

Comment: @sloth sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I've used "key = pygame.key.get_pressed()" in my "handle_keys" function. Do you mean that I should use it in the loop instead of just in the function?

Comment: nevermind, I think your issue is that your `player.handle_keys()` call is inside your `for event` loop. I can't really tell because the indentation of the code in the question seems broken.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the indenting that was the issue. for some reason, different areas were indented differently to other and it sorta threw off everything. Thanks to @sloth for mentioning the indenting leading to me accidentally fixing it whilst fixing it :P