# I'm trying to detect the collision between two moving Rects in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

So I keep trying to detect two different moving rects in pygame colliding but its just constantly registering a collision. As in the console constantly print lose, but the enemy isn't even touching the ball. The effect I want is just a simple game where the ball has to avoid the tack so that the ball doesn't pop.

```
import pygame
import sys
import math
import random
pygame.init()



size = width, height = 800, 600
white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255, 0, 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

character = pygame.image.load("intro_ball.gif")
charrect = character.get_rect()
x = 340
y = 480
enemy = pygame.image.load("ho.png")
enrect = enemy.get_rect()
ex = random.randint(0, 690)
ey = 0
lose = False




while 1:
     clock.tick(60)
     for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()


     if ey >= 600 and lose != True:
          ey = 0
          ex = random.randint(0, 690)

     collide = pygame.Rect.colliderect(charrect, enrect)


     if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
          if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and x < 690:
          x += 4
     if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and x > 0:
        x -= 4

     if collide:
        lose = True
     else: lose = False

     if lose == True: print("lose")




    ey += 2        
    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(enemy, (ex, ey))
    screen.blit(character, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. A *Surface* is `blit` at a position on the screen. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the top lelft of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `topleft`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments):

```py
while 1:
    # [...]

    charrect = character.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
    enrect = enemy.get_rect(topleft = (ex, ey))
    collide = pygame.Rect.colliderect(charrect, enrect)

    # [...]
```

---

On the other hand you do not need the variables `x`, `y`, `ex`, `ey` at all. Use the features of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.htmlv) objects.
Additionally read [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down)

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame, sys, math, random
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 800, 600
white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255, 0, 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

#character = pygame.image.load("intro_ball.gif")
character = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
character.fill((0, 255, 0))
charrect = character.get_rect(topleft = (340, 480))
#enemy = pygame.image.load("ho.png")
enemy = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
enemy.fill((255, 0, 0))
enrect = enemy.get_rect(topleft = (random.randint(0, 690), 0))
lose = False

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    charrect.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * 4
    charrect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())

    enrect.y += 2     
    if enrect.y >= 600 and lose != True:
        enrect.y = 0
        enrect.x = random.randint(0, 690)

    collide = pygame.Rect.colliderect(charrect, enrect)
    if collide:
        lose = True
    else: 
        lose = False
    if lose == True: 
        print("lose")
   
    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(enemy, enrect)
    screen.blit(character, charrect)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```