# Why am I getting a TypeError error for a subscript

Tags: python, pygame

My friend made most of this and I was going to do the movement part and everywhere I place it, I get the same:

> ```
> TypeError for "'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable"
> ```

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
BACKGROUND = (0, 0, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((600, 400))

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Player.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    player = Player()

    while True:
        screen.fill(BACKGROUND)
        screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

if pygame.key.get_pressed [pygame.K_w]:
    Player.y +=5
if pygame.key.get_pressed [pygame.K_s]:
    Player.y -=5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

pygame.QUIT()
quit()
```

Comment: you fixed it but it doesn't move unless you are pressing the key when it loads then it wont stop moving

Comment: No, that is not correct. See the answer. Everything is working well. I'm very sure your [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) is wrong.

Comment: i copied and pasted it in, how is it wrong?

Comment: I did't downvote. However, there are many obvious problems in your code that you can easily fix yourself if you just learn the basics.

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) is a function! Call the function in the application loop. Use the subscription with the return value:

You have to handle the events in the application loop. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump).

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

---

[image]

```py
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
BACKGROUND = (0, 0, 0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode ((600, 400))

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Player.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    player = Player()

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False 

        screen.fill(BACKGROUND)
        screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            player.rect.y -=5
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            player.rect.y +=5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

See also [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down).