# Making a square move continously in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I am quite new to pygame and I am trying to make this black square move up, down, left, and right. I was hoping I could do it like when I press any of those keys and hold them in the black box would move continuously up. Can anyone help me?
This is my code

```
import pygame, sys
import math

pygame.init()


width = 1900
height = 1000
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
player_color = (0,0,0)
player_pos = [950,500]
player_size = (20)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))



game_over = False

while not game_over:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            x = player_pos[0]
            y = player_pos[1]   

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= player_size
            elif event.key == pygame. K_RIGHT:
                x += player_size
            elif event.key == pygame. K_DOWN:
                y += player_size
            elif event.key == pygame. K_UP:
                y -= player_size
            player_pos = [x,y]

    screen.fill(white)
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,black, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1],20,20))
    

    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: And what behaviour do you observe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) instead of the keyboard events. See [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down).

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed and the movement speed of the player.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

```py
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

width = 1900
height = 1000
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
player_color = (0,0,0)
player_pos = [950,500]
player_size = (20)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_over = False
while not game_over:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player_pos[0] += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * player_size
    player_pos[1] += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * player_size

    screen.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, player_color, (player_pos[0], player_pos[1],20,20))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```