# Pygame holding down keys

Tags: python, pygame

So I've recently been creating games in pygame. I'm making a new one, but the get_pressed isn't working. It works, but when I hold down a button it stops. I have to keep clicking repeatedly. (Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm new)

Code:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    self.direction.x = 1
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    self.direction.y = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

See [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down). [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) is not an event.

You need to set the direction even if no key is pressed:

```py
self.direction.x = 0
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    self.direction.x += 1
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    self.direction.x -= 1

self.direction.y = 0
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    self.direction.y += 1
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    self.direction.y -= 1
```

or

```py
self.direction.x = keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
self.direction.y = keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]
```

Additionally, you need to call `pygame.key.get_pressed()` in the application loop, not the event loop.

```py
class Player:

    def get_input(self):
    
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        self.direction.x = keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
        self.direction.y = keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]

       # [...]
```

```
player = Player()

# apllication loop
run = True
while run:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # in the event loop
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # in the application loop
    player.get_input()

    # [...]
```