# I can't move an image with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
weight=550
height=400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((weight,height))
image=pygame.image.load("Capture.jpg").convert()
ix= 70
iy = 80
speed =10
imageplace = screen.blit(image,(ix,iy))
pygame.display.update()
running=True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pygame.time.delay(10)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pos_x = pos[0]
            pos_y = pos[1]
            if (keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]) and ix > 0:
                ix-=speed
            if (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]) and ix > 0:
                ix+=speed
            if (keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]) and ix > 0:
                iy-=speed
    
            if (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]) and ix > 0:
                iy+=speed
            
            
            if imageplace.collidepoint(pos_x,pos_y):
                print("You have clicked on button")
            else:
                print("Wrong Direction")
```

I tried to move an image with pygame but it didn't work. I am new at this. I couldn't find anything on internet and I didn't understand it.

Comment: Your main loop (`while running`) does not do any graphical update. It should at least contain one `screen.blit(something)` to draw a surface on the screen and `pygame.display.update()` to update the display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down) and you must redraw the scene in ever frame. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

---

Example based on your code:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
width, height = 550, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
image = pygame.image.load("Capture.jpg").convert()
imageplace = image.get_rect(topleft = (70, 80))
speed = 5

running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if imageplace.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print("You have clicked on button")
            else:
                print("Wrong Direction")

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()        
    if (keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]) and imageplace.left > 0:
        imageplace.x -= speed
    if (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]) and imageplace.right < width:
        imageplace.x += speed
    if (keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_w]) and imageplace.top > 0:
        imageplace.y -= speed
    if (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_s]) and imageplace.bottom < height:
        imageplace.y += speed

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(image, imageplace)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```