# Pygame Characther Doens't Move

Tags: python, pygame

Nice day for y'all, peoples

after learning python i'm starting to learn pygame, and for thaat i've been tried to make my first step by doing a rect to move. I did draw the rect and did the following code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rectx = 100
recty = 250

run = True
player = pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(rectx, recty, 100, 60))
pygame.display.flip()


while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        key_pressed_is = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if pygame.K_LEFT:
            rectx -= 8
        if pygame.K_RIGHT:
            rectx += 8
        if pygame.K_UP:
            recty -= 8
        if pygame.K_DOWN:
            recty += 8

    pygame.display.update()
```

but when i run the program, everything is okay except that the rect doens't move. Even when i press any move button, it doens't move and i don't get eny error message, the rect just stay still

what should i do?
and if it is possible, could you explain me why i get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down).
[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) is not an event.
You have to call it in the application loop instead of the event loop.
[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `1`, otherwise `0`
e.g. `if key_pressed_is[pygame.K_LEFT]:`.
Furthermore you need to redraw the entire scene in ever frame. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = pygame.Rect(100, 250, 100, 60)

# applicatiion loop
run = True
while run:

    # limit frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # update objects

    # INDENTATION
    #<--|
    key_pressed_is = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_pressed_is[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.x -= 8
    if key_pressed_is[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.x += 8
    if key_pressed_is[pygame.K_UP]:
        player.y -= 8
    if key_pressed_is[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player.y += 8

    # clear display
    win.fill(0)

    # draw scene   
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), player)

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip()
```