# I was wondering why my playerIMG wont load in pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame

Here is my code below this is my first pygame project any help will be appreciated!
I think its something to do with the

> def player(playerX,playerY):
> pygame.display.update()

block of code. Though when I play around with it sometimes it won't even display my background object and only displays the screen filler black.

```
import pygame

#initializing the game
pygame.init()

FPS = 60
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

#creating the screen and setting the size
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

#setting the title of the window
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Crashers')

#going into our files and loading the image for the background
background = pygame.image.load(r'C:\\Users\\ahmad\\Downloads\\pygame projects\\Assets\\newBackground.jpg')

#player image and model
playerImg = pygame.image.load(r'C:\\Users\\ahmad\\Downloads\\pygame projects\\Assets\\blueShip.png')
#these cords are for the player ship to be in the middle of the screen
playerX = 370
playerY = 480

#creating player function
def player(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(playerImg, (x,y))




# window creation
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    
     #setting the background to black
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
   
    #then changing the background to the image we loaded
    gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
    pygame.display.update() 
    
        # if the keystroke is pressed, the player will move
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX -= .01
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX += .01
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY -= .01
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY += .01
    
    
    
               
def player(playerX,playerY):         
        pygame.display.update()             
clock.tick(FPS)   
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: This post isnt about user input its about why my img wont load into the window.

Comment: No it is not.  This post is about putting event handling in the wrong place, which leads to a complete mess. You obviously didn't try hard enough to solve the problem before you asked the question. Stack Overflow is not a beginners tutorial. Everything you need to know is easy to find out with a little research. Asking a new Stack OVerflow question should not be the first attempt to solve a problem. It should be the very last option.

Answer (score 0):

See [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down). Also learn about [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). Your code must have the correct indentation to work properly.

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

```py
import pygame

#initializing the game
pygame.init()

FPS = 60
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

#creating the screen and setting the size
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

#setting the title of the window
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Crashers')

#going into our files and loading the image for the background
background = pygame.image.load(r'C:\\Users\\ahmad\\Downloads\\pygame projects\\Assets\\newBackground.jpg')

#player image and model
playerImg = pygame.image.load(r'C:\\Users\\ahmad\\Downloads\\pygame projects\\Assets\\blueShip.png')
#these cords are for the player ship to be in the middle of the screen
playerX = 370
playerY = 480

# creating player function
def player(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(playerImg, (x,y))

# application loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    
    # handle the events 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False

    # update the game states and positions of objects
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    playerX += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT])  * 3
    playerY += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * 3

    # clear the entire display or draw the background
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))

    # draw the entire scene (blit all the objects)
    player(playerX, playerY)
    
    # update the display 
    pygame.display.update()  

    # limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with
    clock.tick(FPS)   

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues found:

1. if block for keyboard controls is outside the for event loop.
2. did not call for player function before the pygame.display.update()
3. player function has duplicate

```
while running:

    # setting the background to black
    gameDisplay.fill(black)

    # then changing the background to the image we loaded
    gameDisplay.blit(background, (0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # if the keystroke is pressed, the player will move
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX -= .01 * 100
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX += .01 * 100
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY -= .01 * 100
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY += .01 * 100

    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()

# def player(playerX, playerY):
#     pygame.display.update()
```