# player img wont load onto the window in pygame. Theres no error whatsoever though I just cant see the img on screen

Tags: python, pygame

Here is my code below this is my first pygame project any help will be appreciated! I think its something to do with the

> def player(playerX,playerY):
> pygame.display.update()

block of code. Though when I play around with it sometimes it won't even display my background object and only displays the screen filler black.

```
#initializing the game
pygame.init()

FPS = 60
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

#creating the screen and setting the size
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

#setting the title of the window
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Crashers')

#going into our files and loading the image for the background
background = pygame.image.load(r'C:\\Users\\ahmad\\Downloads\\pygame projects\\Assets\\newBackground.jpg')

#player image and model
playerImg = pygame.image.load(r'C:\\Users\\ahmad\\Downloads\\pygame projects\\Assets\\blueShip.png')
#these cords are for the player ship to be in the middle of the screen
playerX = 370
playerY = 480

#creating player function
def player(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(playerImg, (x,y))

# window creation
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    
     #setting the background to black
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
   
    #then changing the background to the image we loaded
    gameDisplay.blit(background,(0,0))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
    pygame.display.update() 
    
        # if the keystroke is pressed, the player will move
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX -= .01
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX += .01
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY -= .01
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY += .01
    
    
    
               
def player(playerX,playerY):         
        pygame.display.update()             
clock.tick(FPS)   
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Your code is completely messed up. Why do you repeat the question? [I was wondering why my playerIMG wont load in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254140/i-was-wondering-why-my-playerimg-wont-load-in-pygame). Read the linked answers and at least try to solve the problem. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You obviously didn't put enough effort into your code. See [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down)

Answer (score -1):

In your game loop you should normally

- fill your screen black
- draw and `blit` everything to the screen
- update the screen
- catch the events
- let the clock tick

You didn't call the player() function in your loop to draw the player image neither the `clock.tick()` function. You don't need to overwrite the player function. Also if ran without any arguments, you should only have one event loop, otherwise some events could be ignored.

```py
pygame.init()

FPS = 60
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

# window
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Crashers')

# background image
background = pygame.image.load(r'C:\\Users\\ahmad\\Downloads\\pygame projects\\Assets\\newBackground.jpg')

# player image
playerImg = pygame.image.load(r'C:\\Users\\ahmad\\Downloads\\pygame projects\\Assets\\blueShip.png')

# these coords are for the player ship to be in the middle of the screen
playerX = 370
playerY = 480

# draw player
def player(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

# window creation
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:
    # reset display
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
   
    # blit background
    gameDisplay.blit(background, (0, 0))

    ### blit the player ###
    player(playerX, playerY)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
        # move player
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX -= .01
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX += .01
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY -= .01
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY += .01
    
    pygame.display.update() 
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```