# python 3.X lagging player movement

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, pygame, keyboard

I`m trying to recreate pong using python/pygame but I got stuck on the player movement. Whenever the 2 players are moving at the same time, they will lag or even stop moving.

I think this has to do with the way I read keyboard key inputs I have tried to change it several times but still no success.

```py
while run1v1:
clock.tick(60)
window.fill((black))
for event in pg.event.get():
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    playerposY += (keys[pg.K_s] - keys[pg.K_w]) * speed
    player2posY += (keys[pg.K_DOWN] - keys[pg.K_UP]) * speed
```

Answer (score 1):

See [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down).

`pygame.key.get_pressed()` is not an event. You have do the movement in the application loop not in the event loop:

```py
# application loop
while run1v1:
    clock.tick(60)
    window.fill((black))

    # event loop
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run1v1 = False

    # INDENTTAION
    #<--|

    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    playerposY += (keys[pg.K_s] - keys[pg.K_w]) * speed
    player2posY += (keys[pg.K_DOWN] - keys[pg.K_UP]) * speed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while run1v1:
    clock.tick(60)
    window.fill((black))
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    playerposY += (keys[pg.K_s] - keys[pg.K_w]) * speed
    player2posY += (keys[pg.K_DOWN] - keys[pg.K_UP]) * speed
    for event in pg.event.get():
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or an update to your question? In the former case, please read [answer], then [edit] to clarify. In the latter case, please delete this and edit your question instead.