# Python pygame's keyboard move command does not operate

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently trying to build a game through vscode using pygame lib.
My code to move character around with keyboard arrow keys won't apply to my module.

- My module won't close even though I click exit button or esc.
  Any thoughts why its not working?

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init() 


screen_width = 480 
screen_height = 640 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))


pygame.display.set_caption("June's Game")


background = pygame.image.load("D:/Python/pygame_basic/background.png")


character = pygame.image.load("D:/Python/pygame_basic/character.png")
character_size = character.get_rect().size 
character_width = character_size[0] 
character_height = character_size[1] 
character_x_position = (screen_width / 2) - (character_width / 2) 
character_y_position = screen_height - character_height


to_x = 0
to_y = 0


running = True #게임이 진행중인가

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False
        if event == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                to_x -= 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                to_x += 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                to_y -= 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                to_y += 5

        if event == pygame.KEYUP: 
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                to_x = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                to_y = 0
    character_x_position += to_x
    character_y_position += to_y


    #screen.fill((0,0,255))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0)) 
    screen.blit(character, (character_x_position,character_y_position))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

i coudln't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

1. `event` is an object. You have to get the `type` of the event, e.g.:

   <s>`if event == pygame.KEYDOWN`</s>

   ```py
   if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
   ```
2. You have to limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) and to control the speed of the game. Otherwise, the player moves much too fast and immediately disappears from the screen. The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time.

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True 
while running:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                to_x -= 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                to_x += 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                to_y -= 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                to_y += 5

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP: 
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                to_x = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                to_y = 0
    character_x_position += to_x
    character_y_position += to_y

    #screen.fill((0,0,255))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0)) 
    screen.blit(character, (character_x_position,character_y_position))
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

However, there is a better method to move an object when a key is held down (See [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down)):

```py
to_x = 0
to_y = 0
speed = 5

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True 
while running:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            running = False
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    to_x = (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * speed
    to_y = (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * speed

    character_x_position += to_x
    character_y_position += to_y

    screen.blit(background, (0,0)) 
    screen.blit(character, (character_x_position,character_y_position))
    pygame.display.update()
```