# Python while loop bugs out

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a game with pygame in which an object moves and i'm trying to get rid of its previous image by drawing a background colored object in its previous position, but for some reason it just wont work, and i've extracted the part of the code which fails

```
import pygame, sys, math
pygame.init()

player = [250, 250]
size = 50
WIDTH = 10*size
HEIGHT = 10*size
speed = 1
prev_pos = player

W = False

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                W = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                W = False
    print(prev_pos)
    if W:
        player[1] = player[1]-speed
    print(f"wtf? {prev_pos}ww")

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'black', center=(prev_pos[0], prev_pos[1]), radius=20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'blue', center=(player[0], player[1]), radius=20)
    
    prev_pos = player
    print(f"prev pos has changed {prev_pos}")

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

this is the original code you can move with w key

```
a = [250, 250]
b = a
while True:

    if a[0] > 0:
        print(b)
        a[0] += 20
        print(b)

print(f"b has changed {b}")
```

and for some reason when a changes it changes b, now i know it might not be a bug but i can't fix this issue on my own

i tried storing it in another variable, another list and all kinds of stuff but nothing worked

Comment: "when a changes it changes b" the reason being that they are the same object, as indicated by `a = b`. Kids don't learn about pointers anymore these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prev_pos = player` does not create a copy of the list, but only a new reference to the same list. You must copy the elements of the list:

```py
prev_pos = player[:]
```

Complete code

```py
import pygame, sys, math
pygame.init()

player = [250, 250]
size = 50
WIDTH = 10*size
HEIGHT = 10*size
speed = 1
prev_pos = player[:]

W = False

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                W = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                W = False
    print(prev_pos)
    if W:
        player[1] = player[1]-speed
    print(f"wtf? {prev_pos}ww")

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'black', center=(prev_pos[0], prev_pos[1]), radius=20)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'blue', center=(player[0], player[1]), radius=20)
    
    prev_pos = player[:]
    print(f"prev pos has changed {prev_pos}")

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

---

Also see [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down)