# 2 different lines of code doing the same thing returns a different output

Tags: python, pygame

So I was trying to implement basic movement into my "game" when I ran into an issue which I ended up solving, but not understanding why my previous solution didn't work. At first I tried doing `pygame.draw.rect(screen, character_color, character)` where "character" was `character = pygame.Rect(character_pos_y, character_pos_x, character_size_y, character_size_x)` and it didn't move. then I decided to do `pygame.draw.rect(screen, character_color, (character_pos_y, character_pos_x, character_size_y, character_size_x))` and it worked. And it started working.

When I ran `pygame.draw.rect(screen, character_color, character)` my character position was changing in code, but not on the screen. Anyone knows why my previous solution didn't work?

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
#defining
ground_pos_x = 0
ground_pos_y = 400
ground_size_x = 500
ground_size_y = 50
ground_color = (0, 0, 0)
ground = pygame.Rect(ground_pos_x, ground_pos_y, ground_size_x, ground_size_y)
character_pos_x = 200
character_pos_y = 200
character_size_y = 100
character_size_x = 100
character_color = (50, 50, 50)
character = pygame.Rect(character_pos_y, character_pos_x, character_size_y, character_size_x)
fps = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background_colour = (111, 222, 111)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("test")
screen.fill(background_colour)

pygame.draw.rect(screen, character_color, character)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, ground_color, ground)
pygame.display.update()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(fps)
    screen.fill(background_colour)
    #movement
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        character_pos_x -= 10
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        character_pos_y -= 10
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        character_pos_x += 10
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        character_pos_y += 10

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, character_color, (character_pos_y, character_pos_x, character_size_y, character_size_x))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, ground_color, ground)

    #if character.colliderect(ground):
    #    print("works")
    #else:
    #    print("nope")

    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position stored in `character` does not magically change when you change `character_pos_x` or `character_pos_y`. `character` is not somehow tied to `character_pos_x` and `character_pos_y`. You have to recreate the `pygame.Rect` object after changing `character_pos_x` or `character_pos_y`:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        character_pos_x -= 10
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        character_pos_y -= 10
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        character_pos_x += 10
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        character_pos_y += 10

    character = pygame.Rect(character_pos_y, character_pos_x, character_size_y, character_size_x)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, character_color, character)
```

Alternatively, you can also change `character.x` and `character.y` instead of `character_pos_x` or `character_pos_y`:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        character.x -= 10
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        character.y -= 10
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        character.x += 10
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        character.y += 10

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, character_color, character)
```

Also note that your code can be simplified (also see [How can I make a sprite move when key is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961563/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-when-key-is-held-down)):

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    character.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - [pygame.K_LEFT]) * 10
    character.y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - [pygame.K_UP]) * 10
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, character_color, character)
```